# MVC 3 : Page Model not getting updated in Partial View after refreshing the page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange problem. I am trying to perform custom pagination in MVC using jquery. I am doing so by putting my grid in partial view of the parent page. When I update the view after the first time load, my model values are not getting updated on consecutive calls. Can someone please advise?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please show us some related code or we won't be able to tell you what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to refer this post. This could be linked to your problem as well.

[Disable caching on a partial view in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786942/disable-caching-on-a-partial-view-in-mvc-3/25620816#25620816)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a caching problem, try to disable it by putting this attribute on your Controller:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Disable caching for all ajax calls in javascript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: I did look that route as well.. there's no caching implemented

Answer (score 0):

I will seize upon the term grid.   I assume you have constructed some sort of grid using html/razor/javascript etc.  Then you placed it in a partial view.  Now you want that grid to refresh after you do an update.

I have provided a comprehensive solution to the problem of displaying data in grid format using ASP.NET MVC 3 and the jQuery-UI plugin jqGrid.

[ASP.Net MVC 3 JQGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092866/asp-net-mvc-3-jqgrid)

The solution is ajax based and provides full CRUD functionality.  You can convert the grid into a read-only grid if needed.   I have not had any issues with model values not being updated.