# RenderAction and Partials with output caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, renderaction, output-caching

I am currently setting up my mvc4 web application and have a question regarding using Partial views and Render Action.

If I apply output caching to a controller action method, will that save a request to the action method when using RenderAction?

And if I have a view that has multiple partials, is it possible to apply output caching to some but not all partials in the main view? or do I need a controller action for each view and apply output caching to such? I want to set this up to achieve best performance.

Comment: Check the accepted answer of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786942/disable-caching-on-a-partial-view-in-mvc-3