# Disabling caching for MVC Controller Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I know I can write a custom `ActionFilter` for an ASP.NET MVC `Controller` `Action` to set headers in the response that will disable caching.

My question is, is there an out-of-the-box `ActionFilter` in the MVC BCL that already does this? Or must I have to create my own custom one?

Comment: sry is it a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786942/disable-caching-on-a-partial-view-in-mvc-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[OutputCache]` filter:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
      // ....
      return View();
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)